# .htaccess URL rewrite causes CSS issue

Tags: php, css, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^product/(.+)$   /product.php?name=$1   [L]
```

This basically looks for "product/" within the URL and redirects to product.php

product.php is in the root folder: eg. **mywebsite.com/product.php** and when loaded directly looks fine and all CSS works.

However when I go to **mywebsite.com/product/example-product** the redirect to product.php works, but the CSS is lost (It's in a seperate stylesheet).

I do not have a product directory, is this why the CSS won't load? Is it possible to have directories in the URL yet redirect to a file in the root folder?

Ideally, I'd like the following:

**mywebsite.com/product/example-product**

redirects to

**mywebsite.com/product.php?name=example-product**

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Just set a <base> that should fix it i think

Comment: Perfect! I thought it would be more complicated than that, it worked a charm.  Thanks!!

Comment: No problem at all. I'll add it as an actual answer too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is set a `base` tag in your HTML `head`. For example:

```
<base href="http://www.website-example.com">
```